# Django Rest Framework problem in CreateAPIView

Tags: python, django

I have a project with Courses and Sections in it. I am building this project with django rest framework and i have the function that should create a section with 3 fields: course, title and creator. I want to understand how i can take a course slug from url and put it in course field, i mean don't pick course manually. How to implement that?

models.py

```
class CourseSections(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='creator_sections',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course = models.OneToOneField(Course, related_name='course_section', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class CourseSectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseSections
        fields = ['creator', 'title', 'course']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
            user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class SectionsCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = CourseSections.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSectionSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsAdminOrReadOnly]
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'course__slug'

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(creator=self.request.user)
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^sections/(?P<course__slug>[-\w]+)/create/$', SectionsCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='create_sections'),
```

Comment: Question should precisely show that you have tested something, not asking for a solution. Best.

Comment: Looks like you are new to Django. Start with the documentation first and then look around for good articles involving urls, models, etc..